# Nested roles for editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, roles

I have problem with defining access in my Rails 3.2 app. I have User model that can be for example 'admin', 'editor', 'guest'. I use CanCan for their authorization.

Let's assume that my app has model Articles and each Article belongs to single Category. I would like to have options in settings for users to allow specific editors editing articles in specific categories. Is there any easy solution without too much hacking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea to get you started:

```
# app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :manage, Article, :category_id => list_of_permissible_article_category_ids
  end
end
```